# Ionic bottom tabs on mobile and side menu on desktop

Tags: angular, mobile, ionic4

Hi there I'm building an app in ionic 4 and angular, I have a left side menu, but what I want to accomplish is that when I'm on mobile is to have that menu on bottom tabs and when I'm on a larger screen that menu moves to the left side. I have not been able to do this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I would like to implement the same feature with Ionic 5.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for managing responsive breakpoints yourself is a featured tucked away in the Material CDK called Layout:

- https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview

I've used this in the past to add responsive layouts to `ngx-datatable`.

Alligator.io have a [good introduction to this subject](https://alligator.io/angular/breakpoints-angular-cdk/).

One way to use it is to set up some breakpoints, and a variable to store the current one:

```js
  public readonly LAYOUT = {
    XS: 768,
    SM: 992,
    MD: 1200,
    LG: 1600,
    XL: 1920,
    XXL: 2560,
  };
  public layout: number = this.LAYOUT.MD;
```

Then in `ngOnInit` set it up so that this is auto managed:

```js
    // Setting up breakpoint mechanism
    const breakpoints = Object.keys(this.LAYOUT).map(k => this.LAYOUT[k]);
    breakpoints.forEach((maxWidth, index) => {
      const minWidth = (index > 0) ? breakpoints[index - 1] : 0;
      this.breakpointObserver
        .observe([`(min-width: ${minWidth}px) and (max-width: ${maxWidth - 1}px)`])
        .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
          if (!state.matches) { return; }
          this.layout = maxWidth;
          console.log('Layout', this.layout);
        });
    });
```

As to the actual feature you're looking for, this would just be a case of setting up both UI's and then using an `ngIf` to show or hide them with the CDK's information:

```html
<app-some-component *ngIf="layout > LAYOUT.XS"></app-some-component>
```